# Janusgraph returns "Unknown external index backend: search " building mixed index with elasticsearch in Gremlin

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, gremlin, janusgraph

When I attempt to create a mixed index in janusgraph 0.3.0 via Gremlin and Gremlin server I get the "Unknown external index backend: search " error.  Elasticsearch is running and I believe the config file is correct (I've included all that below.

```
gremlin> mgmt.get('graph.janusgraph-version')
==>0.3.0
gremlin>
```

When I run the following...

```
gremlin> IsCurrentVersion = mgmt.makePropertyKey('is current version').dataType(Boolean.class).cardinality(SINGLE).make();
==>is current version
gremlin> mgmt.buildIndex('iscurrent', Vertex.class).addKey(IsCurrentVersion).buildMixedIndex("search");
```

I get...

## Unknown external index backend: search

```
# Settings with mutability GLOBAL_OFFLINE are centrally managed in
# JanusGraph's storage backend.  After starting the database for the first
# time, this file's copy of this setting is ignored.  Use JanusGraph's
# Management System to read or modify this value after bootstrapping.

index.search.backend=elasticsearch

# The hostname or comma-separated list of hostnames of index backend
# servers.  This is only applicable to some index backends, such as
# elasticsearch and solr.
#
# Default:    127.0.0.1
# Data Type:  class java.lang.String[]
# Mutability: MASKABLE
index.search.hostname=127.0.0.1
```

The Gremlin Server startup log has...

```
4060 [main] INFO  com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster  - New Cassandra host /127.0.0.1:9042 added
4085 [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend  - Configuring index [search]
4813 [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend  - Configuring index [backend]
4837 [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend  - Initiated backend operations thread pool of size 8
4931 [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend  - Configuring total store cache size: 219574576
```

Elasticsearch is running as shown by...

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/?pretty'
{
  "name" : "nfZKXFP",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "6QDueUnoQfmKRwuEG-a3nw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.0.1",
    "build_hash" : "601be4a",
    "build_date" : "2017-12-04T09:29:09.525Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.0.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```